# How to use OpsCenter with CCM?

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and want to run OpsCenter on my development cluster which I created with CCM.

I see CCM has a -o option for configuring OpsCenter as mention [here](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm/issues/203).  However, it is not clear how to use this option.

Here is what I've attempted thus far:

```
ccm create test_cluster -v 2.1.2 -o OPSCENTER
ccm populate -n 3
ccm start -v
```

When I open OpsCenter I see: `3 agents failed to connect`

`ccm create -h` for `-o OPSCENTER` shows: `Download and use provided opscenter version to install with DSE. Will have no effect on cassandra installs)`

It's not clear to me how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The '-o' option specifies what version of Opscenter to download and install.  As far as I can tell, it only works if you provide '--dse' when you create your CCM cluster.  DSE and Opscenter support was only recently added, so it may be that no one has done the work to make it work for non-DSE setups.

Here's an example:

```
$ ccm create --dse -v 4.6.0 --dse-username=myusername --dse-password=mypassword -o 5.0.2 -n 3 dse460
Downloading http://downloads.datastax.com/community/opscenter-5.0.2.tar.gz to /var/folders/nw/5f2tsw817ln2smczw1hx_tx00000gn/T/ccm-NwRIFb.tar.gz (68.589MB)
  71920484  [100.00%]
Extracting /var/folders/nw/5f2tsw817ln2smczw1hx_tx00000gn/T/ccm-NwRIFb.tar.gz as version opsc5.0.2 ...
Downloading http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/dse-4.6.0-bin.tar.gz to /var/folders/nw/5f2tsw817ln2smczw1hx_tx00000gn/T/ccm-1_ON_p.tar.gz (511.738MB)
 536595851  [100.00%]
Extracting /var/folders/nw/5f2tsw817ln2smczw1hx_tx00000gn/T/ccm-1_ON_p.tar.gz as version 4.6.0 ...
Current cluster is now: dse460
$ ccm start
```

After my cluster starts  Opscenter is running at http://localhost:8888 with all 3 agents connected.

Since CCM downloads and installs Opscenter Community Edition, it probably can be made to work without the requirement to run DSE.  Since ccm is open source, that might be a nice feature that someone can add.  I think it's useful so I may look into it unless someone else is already on it.

Comment: On top of that, it may be nice to just have CCM configure nodes with the opscenter agent, so an external opscenter install can be used (which is what I think you are trying to accomplish).

Comment: using an external opscenter would be ideal for me.  thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I used this alternative approach:

- Use CCM to create nodes
- Manually install OpsCenter
- Manually install and configure Agents for each Node as explained in [this documentation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/running-opscenter-with-a-local-development-cluster).